can all the dwarfs cross the river?
One hundred dwarfs weighing 1, 2, ..., and 100 kg are located on the left side of a river. They cannot swim. There is also a boat on the same side of the river with a capacity of 100 kg. Each dwarf can move the boat from the right to the left side of the river only once. (So ​​each dwarf can return to the left side only once) (Each dwarf can drive the boat and also the driver does not change during a move.). Can all the dwarves cross the river?
I first tried sending them in pairs, sending 99 and 1, then 1 returns. 98 and 2, 2 returns. 97 and 3, 3 returns, etc. 1 to 50 and 100 remain. but I didn't know what to do after that.
then I tried sending 1 to 13 (summing 91) and 13 returns. then sending 13 + 14 + ... + 18, 12 returns, 12 + 19 + 20 + 21 + 22 (summing 93), then 11 returns, etc. but then, the numbers after 50 remained, and I didn't know what to do with them. I don't know what else to do.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"Each dwarf can move the boat from the right to the left side of the river only once"    I think that limitation kills it.

For an even number $n$ of dwarfs, it is impossible for all of them to cross the river.
Assume we are given a solution for the problem with $n$ dwarfs. With the first boat ride a maximum of $n$ kg can be brought over. For every further ride, a dwarf (weighing $i$ kg) has to return before the boat can carry $n$ kg again, resulting in a net $(n-i)$ kg brought over. As every dwarf returns at most one time, we get a maximum of weight carried to the right side of
$$
n + \sum_{i = 1}^n(n-i) =  \frac{n(n+1)}2
$$
kilograms. This is exactly the total weight of all dwarfs. Therefore, we can only bring all dwarfs across if every trip from left to right is done with a boat at maximal capacity and every dwarf returns exactly once. Only the heaviest dwarf might skip his boat ride back, as his return does not gain any net profit.
Whenever the heaviest dwarf crosses from left to right, the boat is already full, so none of the other dwarfs sail with him. We know that the dwarf of weight $n-1$ kg crosses from left to right exactly twice. Both times, the boat has to be completely full. This is only possible if the $1$-kg-dwarf accompanies him. The dwarf weighing $n-2$ kg has to cross twice, as well, both times in a full boat. As the lightest dwarf already spends both of his trips with the $n-1$-kg one, dwarfs $n-2$ and $2$ have take the boat together at both of their rides. Continuing this way, one sees that every trip from left to right takes exactly two dwarfs over, and their weights add up to $n$ kg. If $n$ is even, the dwarf weighing $\frac n2$ kg takes the boat together with another dwarf of the same weight. There is no other dwarf of his weight, so this is impossible. Thus, $n$ is odd.
ConMan's answer gave a solution for the odd case. In total, the dwarfs can make it across if and only if $n$ is odd.

I believe that it is impossible for any even number of dwarves, but I haven't got a good proof for it.
With that said, here's a strategy for an odd number of dwarves:
Let the dwarves have weight $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2N, 2N+1$.
For $j = 1, 2, \ldots, N$:

Send the boat to the right with dwarves $j, 2N + 1 - j$.

Send the boat back with dwarf $j$.


At the end of this, you will have dwarves $1, 2, \ldots, N, 2N+1$ on the left of the river, and dwarves $N+1, \ldots, 2N$ on the right, with the boat on the left. Then send dwarf $2N+1$ to the right on their own. Finally, for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, N$:

Send the boat to the left with dwarf $2N + 1 - j$.

Send the boat to the right with dwarves $j, 2N + 1 - j$.


This succeeds in getting every dwarf across, and every dwarf except for the heaviest captains one trip going back.
Without a proper proof of the impossibility of an even number, I do suspect that you can show that you need to do the pairing as in the odd strategy to get everyone across, which leaves the dwarf with weight $N$ stuck.

I can't seem to get more than 91 dwarves across..
It's also possible if dwarves 1...10 can sail back twice and the others once.
It's also possible if dwarf 1 can sail back and forth 11 times but dwarves 70 and larger can't sail back at all.
Sometimes understanding variations on the problem might lead you to a solution. But I haven't been able to show that all dwarves with just 1 sailback can reach the right hand side.
It is possible if the 1st dwarf can sail back and forth 10 times and the rest just once.
If you increase the boat's capacity to 111, you can get all dwarves across without modifying the sailback restrictions at all.
I would lean towards this being impossible, but I am just doing a random search over possible strategies. Any heuristic I add like prioritizing smaller or larger folks only worsens my solutions. I can't seem to find an analytical solution, but again, by modifying the paramters, I have been able to find plenty of solutions. However with the weight limit of exactly 100 and sailbacks all set to 1 I simply could not find any solution for this problem. I believe it is impossible but it is not a proof, just evidence.

Incomplete proof sketch for impossibility of this when $N$ is even:
Consider $N=2$, dwarves of weight $1,2$ kg and a boat capacity of $2$. Clearly you cannot get both to the other side, since only one dwarf can travel at a time.
Let $P(N)$ for even $N$ be the predicate that there is no legal way to get $N$ dwarves to the other side with a boat capacity of $N$. Clearly $P(2)$ is true. By way of induction I'll show that $P(N-2) \implies P(N)$, which would definitely prove that $P(100)$, which is what you are trying to show.
Suppose there is no way to get $N-2$ dwarves across with $N-2$ capacity, and consider adding $2$ to the capacity, as well as appending dwarves of weight $N-1$ and $N$. If all dwarves could end up on the right hand side, the one of weight $N$ must sail across alone. However, the state right after the $N$-dwarf arrives on the right hand side is such that a dwarf on the right must sail back, removing their right to sail backwards at any point in the future.
Suppose without any loss of generality that it is possible to sail $N-2$ dwarves across with $N$ capacity. Clearly if that is not true, then $P(N-2) \implies P(N)$ and we're done. Now, the following must occur, if it will be possible to sail $N$ dwarves across with $N$ capacity:

A dwarf with a sailing capability must be chosen to sail back to the left.

The $N$-sized dwarf sails alone across and cannot contribute to captaining (without loss of generality).

Another dwarf with a sailing capability must be chosen to sail back left, since the previous captain will need to end up on the right.

The two chosen captains must not exceed $N$ weight together.


However, this implies that the dwarves of weights $1,\dots,N-1$ can sail across in a capacity of $N$ by only utilizing $N-3$ captains, since $2$ dwarves are needed to take the $N$ dwarf across, and those $2$ unused captains
up until the travel of the $N$ weighted dwarf weigh at most $N/2$ each, since both need to eventually arrive at the right hand side. Keep in mind that the $N$-dwarf cannot go first without loss of generality since they would just have to sail themselves back alone.
The issue with this proof is that it is difficult to directly arrive at a contradiction for when the capacity is $N-1$, given a structure of capacity $N$. It seems close but is there any possible way to modify this proof in order to show the implication? For $N=32$ it is possible to get each dwarf across if you allow a capacity of $34$, but it seems impossible with a capacity of $32$. In that instance it would imply that you can get $31$ dwarves across by only using $29$ captains sailing back but utilizing a capcity of $34$. I suppose this proof isn't going anywhere since the analysis does not directly prove the implication.. But if anyone can figure out a way to modify this so it works, please, write a comment. Thank you.
